# snowflake skip a pull if variable is blank

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a script that pulls a list of tables, and stores each table DB.schema.name as var1, var2,..., var15.

later the script does:
`select * from table($prod_table_8)`

but when var8 is null this fails.  15 was picked arbitrarily as these are sometimes 1, heck they might be 34, ill deal with that later, 15 is fine.  later the script is going to just union everything and if 8-15 is blank that is fine.

here is me assigning everything, this is working, but 8+ in this case are all null and killing everything.

```
BEGIN
SET prod_table_1 = (SELECT prod_full FROM combine WHERE num = 1);
SET prod_table_2 = (SELECT prod_full FROM combine WHERE num = 2);
SET prod_table_3 = (SELECT prod_full FROM combine WHERE num = 3);
...
SET prod_table_15 = (SELECT prod_full FROM combine WHERE num = 15);
END
;
```

later

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_1)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_2)
UNION ALL
...
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_15)
;
```

in my test case 8 is the killer, but next time it might be 2 or 14, or....?

this is what i have, each one of these is only 1 line, fyi

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_7)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_8)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_9)
```

what i want to do is, forgive me, this is going to be **EXCEL** format around my SQL, i just dont know how to do what i feel like would work in excel? ill **BOLD** the excel portion that i am trying to ask how to convert to SQL: ...im not sure how this is going to look, but its a basic IF statement...

**if($prod_table_7 is not null,** SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_7) **,null)**
UNION ALL
**if($prod_table_8 is not null,** SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_8) **,null)**
UNION ALL
**if($prod_table_9 is not null,** SELECT * FROM TABLE($prod_table_9) **,null)**

```
tanks!
```

Comment: I wouldn't structure you process in the way you have - particularly because you have to hardcode the number of records/queries. Instead, using a SQL script, query the "combine" table for the records you want, loop through this cursor dynamically constructing your UNION query, then execute this dynamically constructed statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sql scripting dynamic query to do it .

below is sample example how to achieve this

```
begin 
let var1 varchar := 'abc';--(SELECT prod_full FROM combine WHERE num = 1);
let var2 varchar;
let var3 varchar := 'abc2';
let query varchar := 
        iff(var1 is not null,'select * from TABLE('||:var1||') union all ','')
        || iff(var2 is not null,'select * from TABLE('||:var2||') union all ','')
        || iff(var3 is not null,'select * from TABLE('||:var3||')','');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
return query;
end
```

Comment: thanks!  this looks like it will work!  i can do my own research, but this is new SQL for me.  what do i even google to learn more about the double pipe, and why its now :var1 vs $var1?

Comment: here you go,
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index